# Считать последнее изменение $_SESSION

Tags: php, сессия, методы

Добрыйдень!
Прошу подсказать:

Метод set устанавливает значение сессии (записывает ключ+значение в $_SESSION), метод get должен считывать ранее установленное значение (в методе set, после записи в $_SESSION, присваиваю только-что внесенные изменения в $_SESSION в 2 переменные: $_SESSION['lastKeyChanged'] и $_SESSION['lastValChanged'], которые позже вывожу в методе get).

Чем можно заменить $_SESSION['lastKeyChanged'] и $_SESSION['lastValChanged'] чтобы не забивать $_SESSION ненужными значениями?
При использовании в методе get других суперглобальных массивов ($_POST['lastKeyChanged'] или $_GET['lastKeyChanged']) - не работает, если создать отдельные global переменные в методе set - тоже не работает.

```
<?php
print_r($_SESSION);
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

$checkCheckboxValue2 = isset($_POST['checklastkeyval']) ? 1 : 0;
if ($checkCheckboxValue2) {
    Session::get();
}


if (isset($_POST['setkey']) && isset($_POST['setval'])) {
    Session::set($_POST['setkey'],$_POST['setval']);
}

class Session
{
    public static function set($key, $val)
    {
        //array_push($_SESSION, $session_value);
        $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
        $_SESSION['lastKeyChanged'] = $key;
        $_SESSION['lastValChanged'] = $val;

    }
    public static function get()
    {
        echo "Ключ: " . $_SESSION['lastKeyChanged'] . ", Значение: " . $_SESSION['lastValChanged'];
    }
}

print_r($_SESSION);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <p>Ключ</p><input type="text" name="setkey" value="">
            <p>Значение переменной сессии</p><input type="text" name="setval" value="">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Добавить">
        </form>
        <form method="post">
            <span>Последнее уст. значение сессии</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checklastkeyval" style="display:none" checked>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Получить">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: есть массив SESSION

Comment: Вы сегодня уже задавали этот же вопрос в другой формулировке. Используйте общий ключ ОДИН для $_SESSIONS['my_key'] и работайте с одним ключем как с массивом.
 $_SESSIONS['my_key'][]
Не создавайте новый вопрос а уточняйте в одном, если вы чего-то не поняли

Comment: @DmitryZhdan Если не сложно - посмотрите мой ответ ниже

Answer (score 1):

Переделал код в методе set на:

```
$_SESSION["sessionparams"]["$key"] = $val;
$_SESSION["lastsessionvals"][0] = $key;
$_SESSION["lastsessionvals"][1] = $val;`
```

Теперь метод get

```
public static function get()
{
    echo "Ключ: " . $_SESSION["lastsessionvals"][0] . ", Значение: " . $_SESSION["lastsessionvals"][1];
}
```

работает.

Корректно ли забивать массив $_SESSION лишними значениями? ($_SESSION["lastsessionvals"][0],$_SESSION["lastsessionvals"][1])
Других вариантов использовать глобальные/суперглобальные переменные - нет?

Если вопрос глупый - извините, пытаюсь выполнить задачку из учебника.
Спасибо.

Comment: В идеальном варианте использовать библиотеки для работы с сессиями.
В качестве решения учебной задачи этот вариант подходит очень хорошо

Answer (score 1):

Для сохранения состояния можно использовать и $_POST и $_GET, но это не удобно.
Для примера можете попробовать реализовать интерфейс, использую разные хранилища:
index.php

```
<?php require_once 'controller.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <p>Новое значение:</p><input type="text" name="value">
            <br>
            <input type="hidden" name="storage" value="<?= $storageData ?? null ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
            <input type="submit" value="Добавить">
        </form>
        <form method="post">
            <span>Последнее уст. значение</span>
            <input type="text" value="<?= $lastValue ?? null ?>" disabled>
            <br>
            <input type="hidden" name="storage" value="<?= $storageData ?? null ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="show">
            <input type="submit" name="last" value="Получить">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

controller.php

```
<?php
require_once 'StorageInterface.php';
require_once 'Storage.php';
require_once 'SessionStorage.php';
require_once 'PostStorage.php';

/** @var StorageInterface $storage */
$storage = new SessionStorage();
//$storage = new PostStorage();

$action = $_POST['action'] ?? null;
$value = $_POST['value'] ?? null;

if ($action !== null) {
    switch ($action) {
        case 'show':
            [$old, $new] = $storage->pullValue();
            $lastValue = sprintf('old: %s, new: %s', $old, $new);
            break;
        case 'add':
            if ($value === null) {
                break;
            }
            $storage->set($value);
            break;
    }

    if ($storage instanceof PostStorage) {
        $storageData = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($storage));
    }
}
```

StorageInterface.php

```
<?php
interface StorageInterface {

    public function pullValue(): array;
    public function set(string $value): void;
}
```

Storage.php

```
<?php
abstract class Storage implements StorageInterface
{
    protected $storage = ['oldValue' => null, 'newValue' => null];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->initStorage();
    }

    protected abstract function initStorage(): void;

    public function pullValue(): array
    {
        return [$this->storage['oldValue'], $this->storage['newValue']];
    }

    public function set(string $value): void
    {
        $this->storage['oldValue'] = $this->storage['newValue'];
        $this->storage['newValue'] = $value;
    }
}
```

SessionStorage.php

```
<?php
class SessionStorage extends Storage
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
            session_start();
        }

        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function initStorage(): void
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['storage'])) {
            $this->storage = $_SESSION['storage'];
        }
    }
}
```

PostStorage.php

```
<?php
class PostStorage extends Storage implements JsonSerializable
{
    protected function initStorage(): void
    {
        $data = json_decode($_POST['storage'] ?? '', true);
        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            $data = $this->storage;
        }
        $this->storage = $data;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return $this->storage;
    }
}
```